# Spring 4 + GWT 2.6.0 + min XML configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, gwt, configuration

I would like to create web application using `Spring MVC` and `GWT`. The main purpose is to extremely minimalize `XML` configuration. I know how to set up pure `Spring MVC` application without `XML` configuration (using `@Configuration` and `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` instead of web.xml) but I cannot figure out, how to achieve the same with `GWT`. I tried to add manualy `org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet` to `ServletContainer` in `void onStartup(ServletContext container)` method (overriden from `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`), but it seems like application ignores my class `WebAppStarter` extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` (I simply put syser in constructor of `WebAppStarter` - in pure `Spring MVC` app it prints something on standard err, but with `GWT` - nothing is printed on standard err).

Here are my configurations:

```
public class WebAppStarter extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    public WebAppStarter() {
        System.err.println("======================> WEB_APP_STARTER");
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebAppConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic testServlet = container.addServlet("gwtServlet", new SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet());
        testServlet.addMapping("/TestModule/springGwtServices/*");
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(BASE_SPRING_COMPONENT_SCAN_PACKAGE_NAME)
public class WebAppConfiguration {  

}
```

I have no applicationContext.xml.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

</web-app>
```

Any ideas? Is it possible to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: This might not help. But have you considered not co deploying your UI with services/controllers? Rather have a GWT project interact via REST calls, either w/ RequestBuilder or perhaps w/ RestyGwt?

Comment: honestly - I don't know how this approach works (via REST). For me it is important to write UI in Java (not in JavaScript). Does this solution support this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are already familiar authoring Spring MVC controllers (eg. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ or http://xpadro.blogspot.com/2014/01/migrating-spring-mvc-restful-web.html?m=1).

Then in a separate UI project you could interact w/ those services (eg. http://wpamm.blogspot.com/2013/07/gwt-and-rest-part-2-client-restygwt.html?m=1).

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, it looks like (for now) embedded `Jetty` configuration in `GWT` SDK doesn't support `Servlet 3.0` web.xml-less configuration. I found these issues: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8472 and https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5823
. So for now, the solution is to use external server (like `tomcat` - using `-noserver` mode), but you loose some benefits of embedded `Jetty` (as development mode).

Some solution is to configure `Tomcat` in development mode under `Eclipse` (more info [here](http://cggis.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/setup-gwt-tomcat/)), but I didn't use that, so I don't know if this works.